# UDF Client, Socket Binding and Tags Hack - Need Help

Tags: network, audit, network-access-control, vulnerability-management

Background

For a long time now, I've been working to remove a persistent, if not permanent, malware presence on my computers and phones.  Every attempt at removal has been unsuccessful to date, by me and many others.  I've seen over time, indications of a "hidden" UDF file system on the machines, which was finally confirmed (to an extent) yesterday, when I began looking for UDF filesystem application tools to investigate my suspicions and found udfclient and udftools for Linux.  Running the udfdump application included with the udftools package, gave the output shown below but simply put, I am not a professional in this field and need help with interpretation, understanding and resolution.
My interpretation of the information is that there is a binding connection between my PC, Android devices and a remote server under the control of whoever is behind the attack. From my previous experiences, I believe I am either being reinfected every time I connect to the internet after a clean OS re-install (due to the remote connection), or I have not been successful in any attempt at removal and have been infected since day one.

Questions

1. Can someone briefly explain the general networking concept of how this network connection is ever present, even after formatting the hard drive and reinstalling the OS?  The behavior of the malware and network connection resembles the characteristics of a firmware virus, which I have not  ruled out, and I'm not certain what I've posted below is enough information to make a conclusion.
2. Are the "tags" I see mentioned in the output below, enabling the persistence of the malware, or is there not enough information to answer that question with certainty?
3. The third line of the output has me a little hung up on what is being referenced by the 'disk' device; is this just meaning the main hard drive and not a reference to some other storage disk such as a virtual drive for example?
4. How do I permanently remove the connections and tags seen from the output of the udfdump application?

FYI.... I have removed the large majority of the mappings to condense the length and if there is a request to see the full version, I wil update the post accordingly upon request.

````
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo udfdump -S -s -t -u 5 /dev/sda
Opening disc:
UDF: warning... reading/writing on 'disc' device
Sequential dump of device/file (sector size 512)
00005206     5206   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 0, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          ( 256 00 00 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  65280
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      0
            Max charset lists                  0
            Fileset number                     16812048
            Fileset descriptor number          0
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) `�`
            Fileset id                         (roughly) `�`
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) `0`
            DomainId `` (UDFv 30fe; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 0 within partion space 256 for 16814354 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 0 within partion space 256 for 16832274 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 0 within partion space 65042 for 12542 bytes

00011115    11115   TAG: descriptor 0, serial_num 0 at sector 33562667, crc length 0 bytes
        Sparing table descriptor
            Sparing table Id  `` (UDFv 7269; unknown OS (102, 110) ) (flags=0)
            Relocation table entries          17605
            Sequence number                   512
            Mappings :
                [00000300 -> b7270000]   [802b0000 -> 04000200]   [03000000 -> 00000000]   [0000c927 -> 0200402c]   
                [00000400 -> 00000300]   [de270000 -> 80da0000]   [04000000 -> 03000000]   [00000000 -> 0000eb27]   
                [0200e02c -> 00000400]   [00000300 -> fb270000]   [e0da0000 -> 04000000]   [03000000 -> 00000000]   
                [00000928 -> 0200602d]   [00000400 -> 78350300]   [5f633039 -> 80c76200]   [02000300 -> 03000000]   
                [30395835 -> 75785f61]   [0200c02f -> 00000400]   [00000300 -> 1a280000]   [002f0000 -> 04000200]   
                [03000000 -> 00000000]   [00002628 -> 0300f2ca]   [00000200 -> 00000300]   [3c280000 -> 29cd0000]   
                [02000300 -> 03000000]   [00000000 -> 00005428]   [030034cd -> 00000200]   [00000300 -> 68280000]   
                [59cd0000 -> 02000300]   [03000000 -> 00000000]   [00008028 -> 02004030]   [00000400 -> 61750300]   
                [6765785f -> 38ce7400]   [02000300 -> 03000000]   [00000000 -> 00009528]   [0300b2d3 -> 00000200]   
                [00000300 -> a7280000]   [ccd30000 -> 02000300]   [03000000 -> 00000000]   [0000bb28 -> 0300eed3]   
-> 00537370]   [4554584e -> 5f694944]   [504b7400 -> 375f4353]   [474e5349 -> 5f694544]   
                [41537400 -> 5f554e31]   [56454e49 -> 414c5253]   [52495354 -> 5f694e47]   [504b7400 -> 31324353]   
                [41465f53 -> 41474542]   [6974535f -> 4353004f]   [5245505f -> 4e465149]   [69744f5f -> 534e0041]   
                [5052315f -> 5441494e]   [455f424c -> 004f6974]   [505f4353 -> 52565345]   [454c4943 -> 5f694f43]   
                [4f437400 -> 5f535350]   [474c494e -> 45534552]   [6974505f -> 4b430050]   [5f455337 -> 5f434e43]   
                [54454f4e -> 5f694e54]   [76337400 -> 65795f6b]   [73615f75 -> 00506765]   [53314b43 -> 4d41325f]   
                [4441435f -> 5f695441]   [504b7400 -> 375f4353]   [5645454e -> 50454c4f]   [74005f69 -> 4e454745]   
                [4c5f5241 -> 4d454e41]   [74005f69 -> 4353504b]   [4154375f -> 5f565452]   [49464552 -> 6974595f]   
                [46490045 -> 45525f43]   [5253545f -> 30344132]   [4755385f -> 004f4944]   [45525448 -> 4d454e41]   
                [74005f69 -> 6163636d]   [6b655f70 -> 6d65795f]   [00457468 -> 5f434649]   [545f4552 -> 41355348]   
                [5f473132 -> 44005549]   [495f4546 -> 4e53434f]   [455f4f4c -> 4e54434f]   [4c5f524f -> 49444755]   
                [335f0076 -> 735f746c]   [61746665 -> 65007572]   [495f4546 -> 41444c4f]   [5f494544 -> 47454d41]   
                [55495f47 -> 45464400]   

06151999  6151999   TAG: descriptor 242, serial_num 1327 at sector -1, crc length 0 bytes

06405538  6405538   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 0, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (55043 00 00 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  61955
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      4096
            Max charset lists                  0
            Fileset number                     -687621991
            Fileset descriptor number          0
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) `��`
            Fileset id                         (roughly) `��`
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 1000; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 0 within partion space 256 for -670873468 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 0 within partion space 256 for -670832508 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 0 within partion space 22668 for 4096 bytes

06405541  6405541   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 0, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (55811 00 00 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  61955
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      4096
            Max charset lists                  0
            Fileset number                     -637302650
            Fileset descriptor number          0
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) `��`
            Fileset id                         (roughly) `p�`
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 1000; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 0 within partion space 256 for -620531642 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 0 within partion space 256 for -620523450 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 0 within partion space 41030 for 4096 bytes

06405544  6405544   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 0, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (58115 00 00 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  61955
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      4096
            Max charset lists                  0
            Fileset number                     -452761461
            Fileset descriptor number          0
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) `P�`
            Fileset id                         (roughly) `�`
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 1000; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 0 within partion space 256 for -435951613 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 0 within partion space 256 for -435961788 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 0 within partion space 47308 for 4096 bytes

06405547  6405547   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 0, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (59395 00 00 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  61955
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      4096
            Max charset lists                  0
            Fileset number                     -402442163
            Fileset descriptor number          0
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) �`
            Fileset id                         (roughly) `��`
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 1000; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 0 within partion space 256 for -385638366 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 0 within partion space 256 for -385642247 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 0 within partion space 8442 for 4096 bytes

06405550  6405550   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 0, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (63235 00 00 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  61955
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      4096
            Max charset lists                  0
            Fileset number                     -150765387
            Fileset descriptor number          0
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) `@�`
            Fileset id                         (roughly) `H�`
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 1000; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 0 within partion space 256 for -100429784 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 0 within partion space 256 for -100431812 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 0 within partion space 16500 for 4096 bytes

06405553  6405553   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 0, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          ( 260 00 00 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  61955
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      4096
            Max charset lists                  0
            Fileset number                     33820753
            Fileset descriptor number          0
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) `@`
            Fileset id                         (roughly) `x`
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 1000; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 0 within partion space 256 for 50657380 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 0 within partion space 256 for 50640997 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 0 within partion space 6246 for 4096 bytes

06405556  6405556   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 0, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (2052 00 00 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  61955
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      4096
            Max charset lists                  0
            Fileset number                     134510821
            Fileset descriptor number          0
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) `�
`
            Fileset id                         (roughly) `�
                                                                       `
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 1000; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 0 within partion space 256 for 218390625 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 0 within partion space 256 for 218415306 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 0 within partion space 53450 for 4096 bytes

06405559  6405559   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 0, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (3844 00 00 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  61955
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      4096
            Max charset lists                  0
            Fileset number                     251953284
            Fileset descriptor number          0
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) ```
            Fileset id                         (roughly) `�`
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 1000; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 0 within partion space 256 for 251977912 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 0 within partion space 256 for 251920569 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 0 within partion space 4281 for 4096 bytes

06657853  6657853   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 0, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (   0 00 01 at 00:00:218.218.00.00)
            Interchange level                  0
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      0
            Max charset lists                  0
            Fileset number                     256
            Fileset descriptor number          56282
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) ``
            Fileset id                         (roughly) `�`
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 100; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 60890 within partion space 0 for 256 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 0 within partion space 0 for 0 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 0 within partion space 0 for 61658 bytes

06658744  6658744   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 50701, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (   0 00 29 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  512
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      256
            Max charset lists                  6781
            Fileset number                     0
            Fileset descriptor number          256
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) ``
            Fileset id                         (roughly) ``
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 100; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 22367 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 7424 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 5472 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes

06658874  6658874   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 7424, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (   0 00 02 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  25508
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      256
            Max charset lists                  4913
            Fileset number                     256
            Fileset descriptor number          7424
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) ``
            Fileset id                         (roughly) ``
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 100; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 512 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 8241 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 512 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes

06662434  6662434   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 27024, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (   0 30 24 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  7680
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      256
            Max charset lists                  1280
            Fileset number                     256
            Fileset descriptor number          15759
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) ``
            Fileset id                         (roughly) ``
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 100; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 3614 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 1280 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 4126 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes

06663083  6663083   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 0, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (   0 00 01 at 00:00:234.234.00.00)
            Interchange level                  0
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      0
            Max charset lists                  0
            Fileset number                     256
            Fileset descriptor number          60394
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) ``
            Fileset id                         (roughly) `�`
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 100; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 65002 within partion space 0 for 256 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 0 within partion space 0 for 0 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 0 within partion space 0 for 235 bytes

06663713  6663713   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 23966, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (   0 43 18 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  7680
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      256
            Max charset lists                  768
            Fileset number                     256
            Fileset descriptor number          24222
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) ``
            Fileset id                         (roughly) `�`
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 100; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 7680 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 926 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 7680 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes

06663927  6663927   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 7680, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (   0 00 03 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  23971
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      256
            Max charset lists                  4400
            Fileset number                     256
            Fileset descriptor number          7680
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) ``
            Fileset id                         (roughly) ``
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 100; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 768 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 7728 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 768 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes

06664149  6664149   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 7680, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (   0 00 06 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  1379
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      256
            Max charset lists                  62977
            Fileset number                     256
            Fileset descriptor number          7680
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) ``
            Fileset id                         (roughly) ``
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 100; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 1536 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 43522 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 1536 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes

06664162  6664162   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 7680, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (   0 00 06 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  2403
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      256
            Max charset lists                  62977
            Fileset number                     256
            Fileset descriptor number          7680
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) ``
            Fileset id                         (roughly) ``
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 100; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 1536 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 43522 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 1536 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes

06664218  6664218   TAG: descriptor 256, serial_num 0 at sector 27165, crc length 0 bytes
        Fileset descriptor
            Timestamp                          (   0 00 30 at 00:00:00.01.00.00)
            Interchange level                  768
            Max interchange level              0
            Charset lists                      256
            Max charset lists                  1678
            Fileset number                     256
            Fileset descriptor number          27421
            Logical volume id                  (roughly) ``
            Fileset id                         (roughly) ``
            Copyright file id                  (roughly) ``
            Abstract file id                   (roughly) ``
            DomainId `` (UDFv 100; no write protect ) (flags=0)
            Rootdir ICB found        at sector 7680 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Next extend for fileset  at sector 5006 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes
            Streamdir ICB found      at sector 7680 within partion space 256 for 256 bytes

06838156 Segmentation fault
````

Comment: `udfdump` assumes that you are using it against an UDF file system and will try to interpret everything accordingly, even if no UDF file system is there. *"My interpretation of the information is that there is a binding connection between my PC, Android devices and a remote server under the control of whoever is behind the attack."* - None of the information provided suggest anything like a network or similar and I have no idea how you come to this conclusion. Given these strange information and your unclear conclusions I propose to close the question as unclear.

Comment: It may be better to start with explaining what technical symptoms you are dealing with that indicate you are being continually exploited. With that information, you could theoretically be assisted in identifying the source of the technical frustration rather than starting with the assumption that an attacker out there has nothing better to do that swat down your devices every time you connect to the internet.